# how to upload bar file into blackberry 10 simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

i have .bar file and blackberry 10 simulator.

how to install bar file into blackberry 10 simulator.

i was tried below url

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8K188AFZrdc

but  after download the bar fie ,i got unable to open the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install a BAR file on the BlackBerry 10 simulator use the command `blackberry-deploy` available in the [Native Development Kit](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/downloads/). You will need to specify the IP of the simulator (which is shown in the bottom left of the VMWare window)

For example, in my case the command syntax would be:

```
blackberry-deploy -installApp 192.168.2.131 myapp.bar
```